# Pass value generated in Expression tree to sub-tree

Tags: c#, expression-trees

If I have declared in an outer expression tree:

```
var creatorExpression = Expression.New(targetType);
```

And I want to use this in one or sub-expressions which assign values to the properties of the new instance, e.g.:

```
var assignmentExpression = Expression.Assign(targetMemberExpression, valueExpression);
```

How can I go about this?

At the moment I'm placing all the assignment expressions into an `Expression.Block` but I can't see a way of passing the instance into this block. It takes ParameterExpressions but I'm not passing an instance in; I'm passing in the type which needs to be constructed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like:

```
Type targetType = typeof(MyClass);

var obj = Expression.Variable(targetType);

var creatorExpression = Expression.New(targetType);
var assign = Expression.Assign(obj, creatorExpression);

var prop = Expression.PropertyOrField(obj, "MyProp1");
var value = Expression.Constant(5);
var member = Expression.Assign(prop, value);

var block = Expression.Block(new[] { obj }, creatorExpression, assign, member);
```

You have to remember that `Expression.New(targetType)` is the `new something()`, so if you use it directly somewhere else, you are every time recreating the object. You don't want:

```
new MyClass().MyProp1 = 5;
new MyClass().MyProp2 = 6;
```

you want

```
var obj = new MyClass(); // assign + creatorExpression 
obj.MyProp1 = 5; // member + prop + value
obj.MyProp2 = 6; // not in the example
```

If you know that the property/field you are accessing is a property or a field you can use `Expression.Property` or `Expression.Field`. Both accept `string` as the property/field name or `PropertyInfo`/`MethodInfo` that can be obtained through reflection.

If you have a function that does assignments and that returns a block with the assignments, you can pass to it the `obj` expression, like:

```
BlockExpression MakeSomeAssignments(ParameterExpression obj, Expression value1, int value2)
{
    var prop1e = Expression.PropertyOrField(obj, "MyProp1");
    var member1e = Expression.Assign(prop1e, value1e);

    var prop2e = Expression.PropertyOrField(obj, "MyProp2");
    var value2e = Expression.Constant(value2);
    var member2e = Expression.Assign(prop2e, value2e);

    return new Expression.Block(member1e, member2e);
}
```

Comment: Excellent. Thanks. It was assigning the new instance to a variable that I was missing. Many passes through the docs and I still missed the `Expression.Variable` method. Many thanks